# How can I convert SRTEXT to PROJ4TEXT with QGIS

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql

I have a SRTEXT like this: `GEOGCS["My Data",DATUM["Not specified (.....`

I want to get PROJ4TEXT of this STREXT.

Can I get it from QGIS. Because I want to insert it in Postgresql SPATIAL_REF_SYS table. (or I need PROJ4TEXT data to use this projection)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write the text (which is called WKT) into a text file `mycrs.prj` , and run gdalsrsinfo on that. Running in the OSGE4W (or Linux/MAC) shell

```
gdalsrsinfo mycrs.prj >out.txt
```

should report the proj4 string and the WKT definition for postgis.

Comment: should I install any program to linux. gdalsrsinfo  command did not work.

Comment: The gdal package from ubuntugis should be installed. this is not yet available for trusty, but for all earlier OS versions.